# printing statement from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
text = 'hello'
vowels = 'aeiou'


for char in text.lower():
    if char in vowels:




print(minimum_dict)
```

How can I make it so this program I wrote prints "vowel x occurs y amount of times".

I tried but I can't get it to work properly, the program Is where there is an input of a word and it checks to see the least frequent vowels which occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the dictionary to get the key and value. `items` returns a tuple pair.

Include the part below in your code to print the desired result:

```
for key,value in minimum_dict.items():
    print("Vowel ", key, "occurs", value ," times")
```

`minimum_dict.items()` returns a list of items which have the `key` into the dictionary and it's associated `value`:

`value` in this case is equivalent to `minimum_dict[key]`.

Comment: Code only answers aren't very helpful. Reference [answer] and add an explanation. It's also not necessary to copy his entire code set, only the parts you've changed

Comment: @makavelllli I added an edit, but the short version is `value` in this case is equivalent to `minimum_dict[key]`. That's what `minimum_dict.items()` does for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be simplified using [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> text = 'hello'
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> vowel_count = defaultdict(int)
>>> for c in text:
...     if c in vowels:
...         vowel_count[c] += 1
...
>>> vowel_count
{'e': 1, 'o': 1}
```

---

In case you had to store the count of all characters, this code could be further simplified using [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) as:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for vowel, occurrences in minimum_dict.items():
    print("vowel", vowel, "occurs ", occurrences, "times")
```

This will loop through your dictionary of the minimally occurring vowels, and for each vowel/occurrence pair will print the string "vowel", the actual vowel, the string "occurs", the number of occurrences, and the string "times".

The print() function takes any number of unnamed parameters and converts them to strings and then writes them to output.